# Multiple HTTP requests in Node-RED

Tags: node.js, node-red

I need to do HTTP request on each url in array in Node.red. Basically I want to filter URLs by their API response. How do I do this? I cannot find any "loop" nodes or anything.

Answer (score 3):

There's a splitter node (node-red-contrib-splitter) which splits a payload-array into separate messages. When a message (msg) arrives, the configured variable will be iterated over.

See: https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-red-contrib-splitter

Comment: Yeah, I use splitters now.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, solved it. I've made node that expects array of URLs in `msg.items` and inserts them one by one in `msg.payload` (request metadata goes to `msg.itemData`), while collecting real `msg.payload` into `msg.itemsResult`. Switch after node decices to fire loop step or (if `msg.payload == false`), fire "result pin".

[image: loop in Node-RED]

After i got it working, I saw you can return two or more values from one node, by returning array of messages, so it should be possible to make loop in one node, w/o Loop Switch.